# psychopy, changing poligon characteristics with keyboard

Tags: python, psychopy

I need to run a test where the subject is able to rotate a line with the keyboard during the test.

I have been looking a lot, but I have not found a good answer.

So far I have tried this:

```
p = 0
polygon = visual.Line(
    win=win,
    name='polygon',
    units='cm', 
    start=(-(2, 0.5)[0]/2.0, 0),
    end=(+(2, 0.5)[0]/2.0, 0),
    ori=p,
    pos=(0, 0),
    lineWidth=1,
    lineColor=[1,1,1],
    lineColorSpace='rgb',
    fillColor=[1,1,1],
    fillColorSpace='rgb',
    opacity=1,
    depth=0.0,
    interpolate=True
)

while True:
   resp_key = event.waitKeys(keyList=['n','m','return']) 

   if resp_key == 'n':
      p = p-1
   elif resp_key == 'm':
      p = p+1
   elif resp_key == 'return':
      break
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After altering the value of `p`, you then need to actually apply it to your line object to update its characteristics, and then draw it to the screen.

e.g. something like:

```
polygon.ori = p
polygon.draw()
win.flip()
```

Also, note that `event.waitKeys()` returns a list of keys, even for just a single keypress. So your checks for keys should actually look like this:

```
if 'n' in resp_key:
```

rather than:

```
if resp_key == 'n':
```

Also check out the `shapes.py` demo under the Demos menu in PsychoPy coder view for some examples of dynamically updating polygons. Although that demo doesn't use keyboard interaction, it might still be useful for you.